# Common roots of degree 4 polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Find the common roots of $x^4+5x^3-22x^2-50x+132=0$ and $x^4+x^3-20x^2+16x+24=0$ Hence solve the equation

Comment: What have you been able to do yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: There are a few ways to do this, one is to find the roots of one polynomial (using something like the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and then the quadratic formula) and plug them into the other polynomial to see if they're roots.  Another way to do this is to find the [polynomial gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) and find the roots of that polynomial.

Comment: Solve *which* equation?

Answer (score 4):

*HINT*: Let $\alpha$ be a common root of both the equations. Hence, it would satisfy both of them. Subtract both the equations, you get $$4\alpha^3-2\alpha^2-66\alpha+108=0$$ It gives the roots $\frac{-9}{2},2,3$. Check that $\frac{-9}{2}$ will not be a common root. I hope you can take it from here. The question reduces to a quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Call them $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  You can do a polynomial version of Euclid's algorithm.
Note that $f(x)-g(x)$ is a cubic polynomial.  So $x*(f(x)-g(x))$ is another quartic.
Then $4f(x)-x(f(x)-g(x))$ is another cubic.  The difference between two cubics with equal leading term is a quadratic.  That should be enough to find the answer.